# Impressão de lixo em matriz string em C

Tags: c

Questão do código:Crie um programa que receba do usuário dois
vetores de tamanho 5, cujo elementos são os nomes de pessoas
(tamanho máximo 10) que irão dançar na quadrilha de uma festa
junina. Após isso, o programa deve percorrer os dois vetores
juntando os i-ésimos nomes de cada vetor em uma matriz 2x5, ou
seja, serão formados pares entre os dois vetores (formando a fila para a quadrilha). Por fim, exiba a matriz construída.

**informação**:tive a ideia de criar uma matriz 2x5, e depois fazer sua transpostas, porém em sua impressão apresenta lixo de memoria, gostaria de saber como arrumar este problema, e se está parte do codigo que gera a matriz transposta está correta:

```
 //Matriz Transposta
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        strcat(transQuadrilha[j][i],quadrilha[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%s ",transQuadrilha[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 2
#define M 5
#define LIM 10
int main(){
    int i,j;
    char quadrilha[N][M][LIM];
    char transQuadrilha[N][M][LIM];
//prenximento do vetor tipo char
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        if(i==0){
        printf("Insira os nomes dos acompanhantes: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",quadrilha[i][j]);
        getchar();
        }else{
        printf("Insira os nomes das acompanhantes: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",quadrilha[i][j]);
        getchar
        }
    }
}
//MAtriz
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M; j++){
        printf("%s ",quadrilha[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
printf("\n");
//Matriz Transposta
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        strcat(transQuadrilha[j][i],quadrilha[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%s ",transQuadrilha[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Se você tem uma matriz a[N][M] então sua transposta será: at[M][N] e não com as mesmas dimensões como você declarou.

Comment: acho que o problema é a concatenação, vou trocar por _strcpy_ em vez de _strcat_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 2
#define M 5
#define LIM 10
int main(){
    int i,j;
    char quadrilha[N][M][LIM];
    char transQuadrilha[M][N][LIM];
//prenximento do vetor tipo char
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        if(i==0){
        printf("Insira os nomes dos acompanhantes: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",quadrilha[i][j]);
        getchar();
        }else{
        printf("Insira os nomes das acompanhantes: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",quadrilha[i][j]);
        getchar();
        }
    }
}
//MAtriz
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M; j++){
        printf("%s ",quadrilha[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
printf("\n");
//Matriz Transposta
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        strcpy(transQuadrilha[j][i],quadrilha[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%s ",transQuadrilha[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
}
```

**problema encontrado**:  havia a impressão de lixo, pois, na parte do código abaixo, aparecia a função *strcat*(que somava o que tinha na `quadrilha[i][j]`com `transQuadrilha[j][i]` )em vez de *strcpy* que copiava a string para a matriz.

```
//Matriz Transposta
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        strcat(transQuadrilha[j][i],quadrilha[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%s ",transQuadrilha[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
}
```